# Integrate Alexa app into existing website

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-lex

Given the scenario:

1. I have an existing website
2. I have an alexa skill kit app

Is there anyway that a user can press a button on the webpage, speak and aws backend will process it and send it to my request handlers?

If this is not available with alexa would I be able to do this with lex?

Comment: Amazon Lex is the right tool for your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Lex is able to do this instead of Alexa.

But be aware that Lex and Alexa have surprisingly different Request and Response JSON formatting so be prepared to restructure your Alexa request handlers to accept and respond appropriately to Lex.

Side Note: the Lex request does have one large perk over Alexa's which is that Lex provides you with the exact user input (or the audio input interpretation) in a field named 'inputTranscript'. So while in Alexa you have to rely on the slots being filled based solely on Alexa's interpretation of the input, in Lex you can parse the input yourself and improve your bot's recognition of slot values.